# How to solve "Connection timed out after 60051 milliseconds" cURL with PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl, connection-timeout

I'm trying to get JSON data from 51 URLs using cURL in Php & recently , I'm stuck with an issue of Connection Timeout & it displays data return bool(false).

Here is error message :

```
Curl Error no :28
Curl error message :Connection timed out after 60051 milliseconds
Count Value : 0
bool(false)
```

And Here is my Code :

```
foreach($this->state_list as $short_code => $state_name_value) {
            // echo "Key=" .$short_code . ", Value=" . $state_name_value;

            $legislator_of_state_Url = "https://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/?state=".$short_code."&chamber=upper"; 

            echo "URL : ".$legislator_of_state_Url."<br/>";
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$legislator_of_state_Url);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,60);
            $feed = curl_exec($curl);

            echo "Curl Info :".curl_getinfo($curl) . '<br/>';
            echo "Curl Error no :".curl_errno($curl) . '<br/>';
            echo "Curl error message :".curl_error($curl) . '<br/>';
            curl_close($curl);
            // print_r(json_decode($feed,true)); 
            $jsonarray = json_decode($feed, true);
            echo "Count Value : ".count($jsonarray);

            if(count($jsonarray) == 0)
            {
                var_dump($feed);
            }
}
```

Every time whenever I run this code 2 random URLs out of 51 returns this error hence I'm not getting any JSON data

What could be the solution ?

Comment: Probably you ran into a rating limitation from the server. It might have banned you for a moment after you did so many requests in short succession. Although that would be a pretty low limit....

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increase the time limit of the script execution then use this

```
set_time_limit(seconds);
```

but there can be some other issues like the url might not be responding at all,you can also check manually the 2 url which are giving the error

Comment: I have checked all 51 URLs separately & each one of them are working.

Comment: then increase the time limit to 100 seconds and see if it works

Comment: also you can use set_time_limit(0)//no limit

Comment: tried set_time_limit(seconds); and curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,100); still getting error .